# How do you parse a param variable as a symbol in Clojure?

Tags: parsing, variables, clojure, compilation, scope

I want to pass in a symbol as a parameter to a function and have that symbol captured as either quoted or a string so it can be concatenated with `-a` tagged on at the end and then use the newly generated symbol to define an atom. But is there some way to do this before the symbol gets evaluated?

```
(defn sym-a [variable] (symbol (str variable "-a")))


   (defn sym-val [old-sym]
      (let [ new-sym (sym-a old-sym)]
        `(def ~new-sym (atom nil))))
```

It works when I use a macro, but I wonder if there is some way to avoid this?

```
(defmacro sym-val [old-sym]
   (let [ new-sym (sym-a old-sym)]
    `(def ~new-sym (atom nil))))
```

Comment: (name (symbol "x")) ; Is this what you mean?

Comment: That isn't working. Can you tell me where I should use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a symbol is evaluated, it is resolved in the current binding context unless you explicitly prevent evaluation using `quote` or its shorthand `'`.

e.g.:

```
(def foo-log 42)
(log-name foo)
;; CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: foo in this context, compiling:(/tmp/form-init735849253251327390.clj:1:1)

(log-name 'foo)
=> foo-log

(eval (log-name 'foo))
=> 42
```

You can write a macro, where the parameter list is not evaluated and return the created symbol for evaluation.

```
(defmacro log-name-macro
  [channel-name]
  (log-name channel-name))

(log-name-macro foo)
=> 42
```

In your example, you would now be required to write `log-put` as a macro.

I don't recommend this approach to solving your problem at all.

Comment: I ended up using a map with :channel and :buffer keys. The :buffer value is an atom containing a vector that gets swap!-ed with a conj or a pop whenever a put or take is made, via special functions. One reason I asked this question was to see if what I was considering before could even be accomplished. I guess the answer to that is "only with macros". Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: Hey man, I'm sorry to bother you but if you could look over the edit of my question and reformulate your  answer I would be really grateful. I tried to narrow it down to what I really want to get at, because I still feel like there could be something that I don't grasp about the different times in Clojure. Thanks again.

Comment: Your macro should work fine. You don't have to end the symbol with `#`, since it won't be part of the form returned by the macro before evaluation (the quoted form). You should only use symbols ending with `#` if they will be bound within the form returned by your macro - they will be replaced with symbols generated via `gensym` and you don't have to worry about them shadowing other bindings. Since you unquote `new-sym#` in it, it won't be part of the returned form so you can just call it `new-sym`.

Comment: Ok thanks. I guess this really highlights the usefulness of macros: they can really go where no function has gone before. Note taken about the gen-syms.

Comment: You can use them to transform code before it is evaluated. It also highlights the usefulness of Lisps "code as data": You may want to check out http://clojure.org/lisp